# Fan and power lights remain turned on after shutting down PC

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, shutdown, fan

When I shut down my computer, the screen goes black as normal, but the power light remains turned on, and the fan doesn't stop.

If I hold down the power button for 4 seconds, it turns off, but I would like to avoid doing so every time.

I've read a lot of similar or identical questions, but none of their answers solved my problem.

I've tried:

- Disabling quick boot,
- Running the "Power Troubleshooter",
- Updating all of the drivers,
- Doing a clean boot by disabling all (except system) services.

But, unfortunately, none of the above solved the issue, and the event log doesn't show anything related to it.

The computer is an Acer Aspire 5560 with an AMD processor, a Windows 10 Pro operating system, and a hard disk with GTP partition table.

Comment: Look in the event logs. See if something is indicated as preventing the full shutdown. You should try a live disc and see if you can shut down the system from there.

Comment: The partition style of your disk is it MBR or GPT? (can be found in Disk Management)

Comment: @Appleoddity Unfortunately, I haven't found anything related in the event log. And... what's a live disk, and what should I do with it?

Comment: @Shifty My disk is in GPT format.

Comment: I found this post on the Acer forum which states that it's a bug with the bios in combination with GPT:
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/352632/acer-aspire-5560g-shutdown-reboot-issue
This is for the 5560G but the normal 5560 might have this bug as well.
It might be fixed in  the latest version of the bios.
You can also change to MBR but you have to boot in legacy mode when your boot disk is MBR partitioned.
There aren't any real downsides to booting in legacy mode when your boot disk is below 2 TB as far as I know.